# exponentials with different base

Tags: exponentiation

What rule can I use when solving exponentials like this one $\frac {2^6 \cdot 5^8 \cdot 3}{100^3}$

I know how to solve exponentials when the bas number is the same with these formulas $x^m \cdot x^n = x^{(m+n)}$, $(x^m)^n = x^{(m \cdot n)}$, $\frac {x^m}{x^n} = x^{(m - n)}$.

But what do I do when the the problem looks like this $\frac {x^6 \cdot y^8 \cdot z^1}{c^3}$.

Thanks!!

Comment: Hint: What are the prime factors of 100?

Comment: That solved it, I was not aware of the prime factor of 100. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint** :$100 = 25*4$
I am sure you can now do the rest